# Add 'Guid' column with NewId() as default value, does not work properly

Tags: sql-server, guid, default-constraint

I have to add a column called 'Guid' that should be have default value. It's not primary-key.
So, I did it as below:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD [Guid] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT(NewId())
```

Ok, now I have a column that has acceptable value. But after insertion a new row, the Guid column's value is

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

I tested it with another name:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD Guids uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT(NewId())
```

and there is no problem with this. It seems that the main problem is the name of column (`Guid`), maybe. Is that true?
So, How can I fix that, since I can't use another name for it.

Comment: Can we know the problem or issue in detail ??

Comment: *GUID* isn't actually a keyword in SQL Server (reserved keywords documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx). I'm not sure how this is happening as I just tried it and I get normal GUIDs, so this comment is just about pointing out that it's not a keyword. Maybe you should provide more detail about the rest of your table schema?

Comment: not able to repro the issue on 2012 .Not sure if this occurs on any version as well .`create table #test
(
id int,
id1 int
)



ALTER TABLE #test ADD [Guid] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT(NewId()) 




insert into #test
(id,id1)
values(1,1)


select * from #test`

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Can you show your test INSERT statement?

Comment: I used Entity frame work. Thanks. The problem was not the SQL. The Guid has an equivalent in my model (application), unlike Guids. So, in insertion by application, the Guid passed null and since has value (null) replaced by 00000000-0000-0000-0000000000000. But Guids not passed. So uses default value.